# Receive Push Notification with Node.js webToolkit

Tags: node.js, push-notification, node-webkit

I'm developing a desktop application using Node-Webkit.

Now I need to receive push notifications from somewhere.
This is what happens:
1) An android application sends a message to my WebApi server 
2) My WebApi server receives that message and forwards it to the Node-Webkit desktop application

The desktop application can't poll the server, so I need a callback that "wakes up"
the desktop application to show the message on the screen.

So I need a service that can send push notifications to an Node-Webkit client.

Is there a way to do it?

Thanks a  lot!

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve this by using socket.io

http://socket.io/